# How do I make one service dependent on another in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-service, service, dependencies

If I view properties for a service, I can see the "Dependencies" tab, but I can't assign other services to this tab.

I have two services that start on startup, a server and a database. The server depends on the database - if the db hasn't started, the server doesn't work. (However, it does actually fail as a service, so I can't use the Recovery tab.)

How do I make the second service dependent on the first service, so that they always start up in the correct order?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From a command prompt running with admin credentials:

`sc config <server_service_name> depend= <database_service_name>`

Read more at this [sc.exe documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/sc-config).

Comment: Wow, that's much easier, will try that next time.

Answer (score 2):

Following the steps here worked perfectly for me:
[Boyce.us](http://www.boyce.us/windows/servertipcontent.asp?ID=7)
Long story short:
regedit.exe, HKLM/System/CurrentControlSet/Services/(your service)
Add a multi value key named DependOnService
Add the dependency service name

Comment: Thanks, done that and the dependency looks to be created.
(I'll restart later to verify it works and accept this answer then.)